# airflow create dag based on content downloaded

Tags: google-cloud-platform, airflow

How can i create a dag dinamically using content downloaded from Google Cloud Storage?

i have a YAML file on Google Cloud Storage like below:

```
conf_id_1:
  attributes: values
...
conf_id_n:
  attributes: values
```

and inside my dag i want to create dinamically a dag based on content downloaded:

```
with DAG(....) as dag:
     with NamedTemporaryFile(mode='w', delete=True) as f:
        get_conf_content = GCSToLocalFilesystemOperator(
            task_id="download_file",
            object_name=config_filename,
            bucket=bucket,
            filename=f.name,
            dag=dag
        )
        config_list = read_yaml_file(f.name) 
        for conf in config_list:
            do_stuff = DummyOperator(
               task_id='do_stuff',
               dag=dag
            )
```

but it seems i can't do that, airflow show me this error:

```
for conf in config_list:
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

Comment: Have you tried importing yaml and use `yaml.safe_load(f.name)`? Are you using that in your `read_yaml_file`?

Comment: It looks like something is not working properly on your read_yaml_file(_) function. Could you please share the function code?